# how to import the  ZXing library for my app for Encoding QR codes(while there is preinstalled ZXing scanner app for my mobile)

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am trying to do an app to create a final QR code for the information of multiple barcodes
that I have scanned.
I am wondering how would you import the ZXing lib to your code?
Assume that user already has ZXing scanner in their mobile, can I just connect with the app to generate the barcode without importing all  the lib since it will make my app heavy?

For importing , QRencoder.java from ZXing, what are the necessary part of codes that I need? 
Or is it even possible?

I  found this two months ago : http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/
And I have tried installing that apache but it is so painful process for me. So is there any other ways around?

Regards

Thet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use Intents. You don't need any code beyond the bit of integration code here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  The same class has methods for encoding a barcode on screen.

Comment: hi thanks for the very quick response, but what i wanna do is to ENCODE QR... not just for scanning

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I said in my answer: "The same class has methods for encoding a barcode on screen."

Comment: hi Sean, i think my english is not good, what i mean by encoding is to Write the QR code ..not just reading it, can i do that with Intent?

Comment: Yes. Please look at the `IntentIntegrator` class as I've said.

Comment: I found some sample codes but I would like to know how to embed the URL in QR code pls because what I found is just to embed some strings ,also do i need license for IntentIntegrator class? from here http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 , I am just doing for a school project.

Comment: i ve checked IntentIntegrator, and I didn't see anything related with URL embedding in QR? I saw the text to store and generate though.